# Minimum number of moves to scramble a matrix

Tags: matrices

I have an $N\times N$ matrix which I'd like to scramble. 
I use $2$ operations :

$1:$ circular shift of a row (randomly chosen between $1$ to $N-1$)

$2:$ circular shift of a column (randomly chosen between $1$ to $N-1$)
when I shift all the rows and columns I get a scrambled matrix. I want to know if I can get to this scrambled state with fewer shifts. 
Do I need to solve this problem using graph theory? how?

Example :

matrix :

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3\\ 
4&5&6\\
7&8&9
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

second row circular shift ( shift $= 2$ )

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3\\ 
5&6&4\\
7&8&9
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

$\dots$

final scrambled matrix after $6$ circular operations on rows and columns:

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
3&2&6\\ 
7&5&4\\
9&1&8
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

I want to know if I can get to this matrix with less than $6$ operations.

Thank you.

Comment: what is your definition of circular shift? Not the classic one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift. A circular shift of  $(1,2,3)$ would be $(2,3,1)$ or $(3,1,2)$ but never $(3,2,1)$. Moreover the scrambled matrix you give has not been constructed by these shift movements because the latter are even permutations and the given scrambled matrix is an odd permutation.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake. my defenition is the classic one. Thank you for noticing.I wrote this with a lot on my mind and had some typing errors. sorry again.
The last matrix is constructed by 6 shifts. one row shift then one column an so on.

Comment: Sorry that I have to bother you again but the matrix stands for the permutation $(1,9)(2,5,8,7,4,3,6)$ and this is an **odd** permutation, but circular shifts are all **even** permutations so it is impossible to obtain this matrix with circular shifts.

Comment: I didn't remember the procedure so I did another one and think this one is accurate. 
operations are :
row 2 shift : 2 / col 1 sh : 2 / row 3 sh : 1 / col 3 sh : 2 / row 1 sh : 1 / col 2 sh : 1 .

Comment: @Nimda Thank you for your comments. I learned something today.
one other thing. can you find the parity of permutation for a matrix as if it's a vector ???